# compare two worksheets, fill in missing data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two lists in two separate worksheets. They are both organized into 3 columns [Last, First, ID]. I have been filling in the ID column in Sheet 1 (~600 rows). Sheet 2 (~900 rows) is not in the same order as Sheet 1 but has many of the same Last, First entries (eg. Smith, John is in Row 1 in Sheet 1, but is in row 57 of Sheet 2).

I want to fill in the IDs from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 (essentially fill column 3) if the Last, First matches. I have tried VLOOKUP and some other functions but since the lists are not in the same order/they are not the same list I have been unable to do it.

Any help with how to do this would be much appreciated!! This is my first time posting so I apologize for any formatting mistakes and such.

Thank you!!!

I have tried using VLOOKUP and conditional formatting. For the first few entries that are in the same order in both the lists (eg. Row 1 & 2 are the same for Sheet 1 and 2 but change after) the matching worked but then the cells were either blank or I received and error message.